# Check if the SQL query is returning a value

Tags: php

I am trying to show a message when my SQL query returns a value (row). But this isnt working. I am using: `if ($res->num_rows > 0) {` but this part of the code isnt doing what I want. How can I `echo 'Yes';` if my query is returning a value?

Here is my full code:

```
<?php

 $user_name = "root";
 $password = "";
 $database = "db";
 $server = "localhost";

 $db_handle = mysqli_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
 $db_found = mysqli_select_db($db_handle, $database);

 if ($db_found) {
     $result = mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT date FROM table WHERE id='1' AND date BETWEEN now() AND now() + INTERVAL 14 DAY");
     $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

     if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
         echo 'Yes';
     }
     else
     {
         echo 'No';
     }
 }
 else
 {
     print "Database NOT Found.";
     mysqli_close($db_handle);
 }

?>
```

Comment: You should consider using mysqli or PDO

Comment: You have the arguments to `BETWEEN` backwards. The lower date has to be first.

Comment: In phpMyAdmin its working

Comment: What is the data type of `id` in your database? Because I see you are using `WHERE id='1'`...but if `id` is an Integer as I would expect, this wont work as you are treating it's value as a string. If this is the case, try `WHERE id=1` instead. In addition, your variable use is inconsistent - you are referencing `$res`, but storing the result of the query in `$result`. You'll want to refactor this too so it uses the correct variable.

Comment: why using mysql_num_rows instead of mysqli_num_rows since you are using mysqli_connect?

Comment: ID = integer. The sql query is working in phpMyAdmin, so I think the PHP part of the code is wrong

Comment: I updated my first post, it is still not working

Comment: Its still not fixed

Comment: What is the output? Are you getting "no"? Try using `mysqli_error($db_handle)` to check that the query is running correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `if(mysql_num_rows($result))`

(But really you should be using mysqli or PDO)

Comment: The SQL query is returning a value in phpMyAdmin. But the php script isnt showing `echo 'Yes';`

Comment: @John There's no way that query could be returning anything in phpMyAdmin, because of the `BETWEEN` problem I mentioned above.

Comment: When I run the query I get the date between today and today - 14 days

Comment: it's not $res but $result.. you can vote this one as correct. didn't see it was so close :)

Comment: Its still not fixed

Answer (score 0):

[`::$num_rows`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) is a part of the [`mysqli`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) interface, however you're using the old (and deprecated) [`mysql`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) interface.

If you stick to mysql, use [`mysql_num_rows()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($res))
```

Comment: The SQL query is returning a value in phpMyAdmin. But the php script isnt showing `echo 'Yes';`

Comment: I got that. It doesn't make your code correct. `->num_rows` does not work on `mysql_` functions, it is part of `mysqli`. You should actually see an error if you turn `error_reporting` on

Comment: I changed it to `mysqli`. See my first post. Its still not working.

Comment: well you can't just change the function names and nothing else. `mysqli_*` functiosn are differetn ones.

Comment: So, what do I need to do?

Comment: Read up how to use mysqli. Sorry, but that's jsut too much to cover here.

Comment: I dont get any mysqli errors. So I dont think the problem is the mysqli part of my code

Answer (score 0):

You have an array as a result in your $res, it isn't an object:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

use mysql_num_rows instead

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   echo 'Yes';
}                         
else
{
   echo 'No';
}
```

Comment: Its still not fixed

Comment: if you still have the problem.. $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

     if ( $num_rows ) {
         echo 'Yes';
     }
     else
     {
         echo 'No';
     }